# Is that static analysis warning a false positive? I can't quiet it down

Tags: c

I have a problem with my code.

scan-build of clang 8.0.0 throws out this warning:

```
main.c:188:12: Out of bound memory access (access exceeds upper limit of memory block)
               putchar(tab[i][p]);
                       ^~~~~~~~~
```

This is the function of interest:

```
void rysuj_glowny(int n)
{
    int nabs = abs(n);
    int size = 2 * nabs;

    if(size <= 0) return;

    char tab[size][size];

    rysowando(size, tab, nabs, n);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(int p = 0; p < size; p++)
        {
            putchar(tab[i][p]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

[This](https://pastebin.com/KM8i2aE2) is the whole code, if it's needed.

This function gets a value 'n', creates an 2D array with dimensions [2*n,2*n], fills out an array using another function (called 'rysowando') and then prints the array.

I tried to quiet down the warning with various conditional expressions (like checking 'size' and 'n' for various limit values), but the warning still remains. Is there a value of 'n' when my code breaks? Thank you for your input!

Comment: I'm surprised this compiles at all. Can you declare an array on the stack, with a size that is only known at run-time...?

Comment: @GeorgP Yes they're called VLAs and they've arguably done more harm than good.

Comment: I think some compilers will alloc the memory and automatically free it in the end of the function, the 'tab' array will actually be allocated behind of the scenes

Comment: Probably OP should try allocating it with malloc and seeing if the problem still persists

Comment: @felipeek The problem is I can't really use pointers in my code, as a part of an assignment. I only wonder if my code using VLAs is really broken, or the warning is a false positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in this case, the static analyzer is wrong. I tried it with clang 9.0 and got a different set of results, but they also look wrong. If you follow the list of steps, you'll see there's something missing:

> /Users/realdarrin/Development/CodeReviewTester/CodeReviewTester/main.c:202:13: warning: 1st function call argument is an uninitialized value
>
> ```
>        putchar(tab[i][p]);
>         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```
>
> 1 warning generated.

If you follow the steps, it gives this:

```
main.c:213:20: Entering loop body
main.c:217:12: Assuming 'x' is equal to 1
main.c:217:22: Assuming the condition is false
main.c:217:35: Assuming the condition is false
main.c:222:12: Assuming the condition is false
main.c:213:5: Looping back to the head of the loop
main.c:213:20: Entering loop body
main.c:217:12: Assuming 'x' is equal to 1
main.c:217:22: Assuming the condition is false
main.c:217:35: Assuming the condition is false
main.c:222:12: Assuming the condition is false
main.c:213:5: Looping back to the head of the loop
main.c:213:20: Entering loop body
main.c:217:12: Assuming 'x' is equal to 1
main.c:217:22: Assuming the condition is false
main.c:217:35: Assuming the condition is false
main.c:222:12: Assuming the condition is false
main.c:213:5: Looping back to the head of the loop
main.c:213:20: Entering loop body
main.c:217:12: Assuming 'x' is equal to 1
main.c:217:22: Assuming the condition is false
main.c:217:35: Assuming the condition is false
main.c:222:12: Assuming the condition is true
main.c:226:20: Entering loop body
main.c:228:9: Calling 'rysuj_glowny'
main.c:187:1: Entered call from 'main'
main.c:192:8: Assuming 'size' is > 0
main.c:196:5: Calling 'rysowando'
main.c:20:1: Entered call from 'rysuj_glowny'
main.c:23:8: Assuming 'n' is not equal to 1
main.c:36:5: Calling 'rysowando'
main.c:20:1: Entered call from 'rysowando'
main.c:23:8: Assuming 'n' is not equal to 1
main.c:36:5: Calling 'rysowando'
main.c:20:1: Entered call from 'rysowando'
*main.c:23:8: Assuming 'n' is not equal to 1
main.c:45:8: Assuming 'startn' is <= 0
main.c:116:8: Assuming 'startn' is >= 0
main.c:36:5: Returning from 'rysowando'
main.c:36:5: Returning from 'rysowando'
main.c:196:5: Returning from 'rysowando'
main.c:198:20: Entering loop body
main.c:200:24: Entering loop body
main.c:200:9: Looping back to the head of the loop
main.c:200:24: Assuming 'p' is >= 'size'
main.c:198:5: Looping back to the head of the loop
main.c:206:1: Storing uninitialized value
main.c:228:9: Returning from 'rysuj_glowny'
main.c:226:5: Looping back to the head of the loop
main.c:226:20: Entering loop body
main.c:228:9: Calling 'rysuj_glowny'
main.c:187:1: Entered call from 'main'
main.c:192:8: Assuming 'size' is > 0
main.c:196:5: Calling 'rysowando'
main.c:20:1: Entered call from 'rysuj_glowny'
main.c:23:8: Assuming 'n' is not equal to 1
main.c:36:5: Calling 'rysowando'
main.c:20:1: Entered call from 'rysowando'
main.c:23:8: Assuming 'n' is not equal to 1
main.c:36:5: Calling 'rysowando'
main.c:20:1: Entered call from 'rysowando'
main.c:23:8: Assuming 'n' is equal to 1
main.c:26:29: Loop body executed 0 times
main.c:36:5: Returning from 'rysowando'
main.c:45:8: Assuming 'startn' is <= 0
main.c:116:8: Assuming 'startn' is >= 0
main.c:36:5: Returning from 'rysowando'
main.c:196:5: Returning from 'rysowando'
main.c:198:20: Entering loop body
main.c:200:24: Entering loop body
main.c:202:13: 1st function call argument is an uninitialized value
```

I've marked one line with an asterisk. To me, it looks like it's missing that `rysowando` is recursive that time. It says that it assumes `n` is not 1, but then doesn't show the recursion. It immediately goes on to the next line.

There are other problems with the analysis, such as when `n` does finally equal 1, the loop inside the `if (n == 1)` section executes 0 times,  even though `offset2` is always equal to `offset + 1`. So something is definitely off with the static analyzer here.